# Spring Data Neo4j 4 is not storing any data

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

I use neo4j-2.3.1 and spring-data-neo4j 4 in my new project. I set up everything as this [post](http://neo4j.com/developer/spring-data-neo4j/) (Spring Data Neo4j 4). However, I can not have any data store into database. 
Here is my neo4j configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("org.drexel.cas.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("org.drexel.cas")
public class RootConfig extends Neo4jConfiguration {
    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("org.drexel.cas.domain");
    }
    @Bean
    public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
        return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7474", "neo4j", "xxxxxx");
    }
    @Override
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }
}
```

Here is the REST api and it just simply call repository to store an object:

```
@Autowired
ProjectRepository repository;

@RequestMapping(value = "project", method = POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Project> create(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> param) {
    Project project = new Project(param);
    repository.save(project);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(project);
}
```

Here is the repository:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface ProjectRepository extends GraphRepository<Project> {

}
```

This is the Project class:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Project {
@GraphId
private Long id;
@Convert(MapJson.class)
private Map<String, Object> attributes;

public Project() {
    this.attributes = new HashMap<>();
}

public Project(Map<String, Object> params) {
    id = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.attributes = params;
}

public boolean equals(Object object) {
    if (object == null)
        return false;
    if (!(object instanceof Project))
        return false;
    Project other = (Project) object;
    if (!other.getId().equals(this.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public int hashCode() {
    return this.id.hashCode();
}

}
```

Here is the converter class:

```
public class MapJson implements AttributeConverter<Map<String, Object>, String> {

    @Override
    public String toGraphProperty(Map<String, Object> value) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type type = new TokenType<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
                return gson.toJson(value, type);
           }

           @Override
           public Map<String, Object> toEntityAttribute(String value) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type type = new TokenType<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
                return gson.fromJson(value, type);
           }

        }
```

After I make a curl post, everything works fine and there are not any exceptions and errors. And then I go to localhost:7474 get fetch all data, I get nothing. 
Here is the log, I did a curl post and curl get. There is not any exceptions

```
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
    WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:dummy' did not find a matching property.
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.29
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server built:          Nov 20 2015 09:18:00 UTC
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Server number:         8.0.29.0
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Name:               Mac OS X
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: OS Version:            10.11.2
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Architecture:          x86_64
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Java Home:             /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_65-b17
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         /Users/bondwong/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp10
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         /Users/bondwong/apache-tomcat-8.0.29
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/Users/bondwong/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp10
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/Users/bondwong/apache-tomcat-8.0.29
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/Users/bondwong/Documents/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp10/wtpwebapps
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/Users/bondwong/apache-tomcat-8.0.29/endorsed
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
    INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
    INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/bondwong/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
    INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
    INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
    INFO: Initialization processed in 866 ms
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
    INFO: Starting service Catalina
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
    INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.29
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:16 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
    INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.drexel.cas.Initializer@28630d24]
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
    00:33:16.781 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
    00:33:16.884 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Dec 18 00:33:16 EST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
    00:33:16.972 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class org.drexel.cas.RootConfig]
    00:33:17.435 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker - Bean 'rootConfig' of type [class org.drexel.cas.RootConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$93dd11f8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    00:33:17.439 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor
    00:33:17.534 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising Neo4jSession
    00:33:18.031 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Starting Post-processing phase
    00:33:18.031 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Building annotation class map
    00:33:18.032 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Building interface class map for 2 classes
    00:33:18.032 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Registering default type converters...
    00:33:18.032 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - Post-processing complete
    00:33:18.032 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.n.o.m.info.ClassFileProcessor - 2 classes loaded in 15 milliseconds
    00:33:18.215 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.mapping.Neo4jMappingContext - Neo4jMappingContext initialisation completed
    00:33:18.359 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising PersistenceExceptionTranslator
    00:33:18.364 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor
    00:33:18.368 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.d.n.config.Neo4jConfiguration - Initialising Neo4jTransactionManager
    00:33:18.377 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1592 ms
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
    00:33:18.404 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
    00:33:18.407 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Dec 18 00:33:18 EST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
    00:33:18.409 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class org.drexel.cas.WebConfig]
    00:33:18.789 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/dummy/{id:\d+}]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.drexel.cas.domain.Dummy> org.drexel.cas.web.DummyService.get(java.lang.Long)
    00:33:18.790 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/dummy],methods=[POST],consumes=[application/json],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.drexel.cas.domain.Dummy> org.drexel.cas.web.DummyService.create(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)
    00:33:18.814 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler]
    00:33:18.851 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Fri Dec 18 00:33:18 EST 2015]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
    00:33:18.938 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 534 ms
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:18 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
    INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    Dec 18, 2015 12:33:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
    INFO: Server startup in 8483 ms
    create...
    get...
```

[image]
[image]
There is no exceptions.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide more information. What does your Project entity look like, how is SDN configured? Any exceptions in the logs?

Comment: @Luanne I add information you asked. There is not any exceptions in the logs.

Comment: And what does your converter look like?

Comment: @Luanne I added my converter, I do not think that causes the problem

Comment: @Luanne I added the log. I did a curl post and a curl get, and there is not any exception of any kinds.

Comment: Can you share your project somewhere?

Comment: @Luanne of course, i will rebuilt it today and share it in github. I will let u know when I finish it.

Comment: @Luanne https://github.com/JavaEEBoy/dummy I upload the project to there.

Comment: The answer from @ceic is correct, never set the GraphId manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not setting the value of the `@GraphId` property by yourself.

```
public Project(Map<String, Object> params) {
    //id = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.attributes = params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The converter is incorrect- it's saying convert from `Project` to `String` instead of `Map` to `String`.

There is already a bug open for issues with generics, so till that is fixed, you'll have to omit them and use instead:

```
@Convert(MapJson.class)
private Map attributes;
```

with the attribute converter

```
public class MapJson implements AttributeConverter<Map,String> {

    @Override
    public String toGraphProperty(Map value) {
        //do something
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> toEntityAttribute(String value) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: im sorry that is a typo error, I did uses AttributeConverter<Map<String, Object>, String>. If I have generics issues, the codes can not be compiled. However, I did not get any exceptions

Comment: There's definitely a run time exception for me when I use this.